# Proper Coding: When returning a new instance of a class

Tags: c++, optimization

Let's say I have a class called `MyClass`, which has two member variables (both being `int`) called `firstNumber_` and `secondNumber_`. This class also has a method called `clone( )` which creates a new instance of the object with the same values and returns that new instance.

The question is, when returning a new instance of the class, do I return it as a pointer, a reference, or just the instance itself?

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass {
private:
    int firstNumber_;
    int secondNumber_;

public:
    MyClass( int numA, int numB ) {
         firstNumber_ = numA;
         secondNumber_ = numB;
    }

    ~MyClass( ) { };

    // This method creates a copy of the object and returns that object.
    // The ( ? ) is there because I am not sure what type the returned value is.
    MyClass ( ? ) clone( ) {
         // Do I just return the new instance? Or do I need to return a reference or a pointer of the new instance?
         return MyClass( firstNumber_, secondNumber_ );
    }
};
```

What's the proper way of achieving this? Note that `MyClass` does not inherit from any other classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the copy constructor, which you don't even need to define, since the semantics of the default one are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `clone()` is usually for returning a pointer to an instance of a polymorphic type, so you can call it on a pointer of the base type and get an pointer to an instance of the right derived type. For simple copying, in C++ you use the *copy constructor*, not a clone method.

Clone method:

```
struct Base{};
struct Foo : Base 
{
  Base* clone() const { return new Foo(*this); }
}:

Base * b1 = new Foo;
...
Base * b2 = b1->clone(); // points to a Foo instance, copy of object pointed at by b1
```

Where the `clone` method us using the (compiler generated) copy constructor.

Using copy constructor:

```
Foo f1;
Foo f2 = f1; // copy assignment
```

In real code you should prefer smart pointers over the raw ones used in these examples.

Concerning the return value, by default you should return by value, although in the polymorphic `clone()` example this would defeat the purpose by slicing the return object into a `Base`. So we return a pointer to an instance allocated dynamically. The intent and ownership has to be clear: in this case, the caller *owns* the pointer, and is responsible for deallocating it. Pre-c++11 you would have to rely on documentation to convey this. In C++11 you can use the smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`, which enforces the ownership and states it clearly.

Comment: The `clone()` method is just an example. What I wanted to learn was _what kind of instance should I return if I want to return a new instance of the class_

Comment: @LanceGray I added a paragraph about that. Return by value unless you really can't.

Comment: Didn't see it until I refreshed. Thanks for the quick (and detailed) answer. I see it gets a bit complicated when digging in deeper. I'll need to have a good read at this. Thanks again.